# How can I compare a decimal represented as a long and int?

Tags: java

Is there a way I can compare (>, <, >=, <=, !=, ==) a decimal represented as a long and int?

If the number is 3214.21 then it would be represented in a class like this

```
long units = 321421;
int precision = 2;
// to get the original number I would do units * 10^precision
```

I would like to be able to do something similar to BigDecimal's compareTo() method. So greater than returns 1, equals returns 0, less than returns -1.

What I am currently doing does not work for some cases. The code that causes it to function that way is outlined below. The method is more or less a proof of concept.

```
public int compareTo(Money other) {
    if (precision == other.getPrecision()) { // fast check if precision is the same
        if (units > other.getUnits()) return 1; // we forgot to inverse/flip here. will be an issue for non-decimal
        else if (units < other.getUnits()) return -1;
        else return 0; // least likely
    }

    int intX = (int) (units / (Math.pow(10, precision))); // converted units whole numbers to int
    int fractionX = (int) (units % (Math.pow(10, precision))); // converts the decimal as an int

    int intY = (int) (other.getUnits() / (Math.pow(10, other.getPrecision()))); // converted units whole numbers to int
    int fractionY = (int) (other.getUnits() % (Math.pow(10, other.getPrecision()))); // converts the decimal as an int

    System.out.println("Test: i " + intX + "| f " + fractionX + "| u " + units + "| p " + precision);
    System.out.println("Test2: i " + intY + "| f " + fractionY + "| u " + other.getUnits() + "| p" + other
    .getPrecision
    ());

    if (intX > intY) return 1;
    else if (intX < intY) return -1;
    else {
        if (fractionX > fractionY) return 1; // this is where the logic fails
        if (fractionX < fractionY) return -1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

Here is my test along with output

```
System.out.println(MoneyFactory.fromString("0.3").compareTo(MoneyFactory.fromString("0.29")));

System.out.println(MoneyFactory.fromString("13").compareTo(MoneyFactory.fromString("0.31456789")));

System.out.println(MoneyFactory.fromString("0.2999").compareTo(MoneyFactory.fromString
("0.3")));
```

Output

```
Test: i 0| f 3| u 3| p 1
Test2: i 0| f 29| u 29| p2
-1
Test: i 13| f 0| u 13| p 0
Test2: i 0| f 31456789| u 31456789| p8
1
Test: i 0| f 2999| u 2999| p 4
Test2: i 0| f 3| u 3| p1
1
```

Comment: why not convert it to a string first

Comment: I haven't measured the performance on that but what I current am using is quite similar to what I would do with a string. It can be seen in the edit along with an explanation with what is wrong with it. But in short, I would think that using String would decrease performance as small as a hit it would be. But my application is going to be using these methods in high throughput so it is crucial (at least to me) to micro-optimize these methods.

Comment: If it's represented in a long or an int **it isn't a decimal.** Do you mean a *fraction?* I see 'decimal' used here to mean everything *except* a number in base-10 notation, which is all it means. Some people here are using It to an the decimal *point,* and others the fractional par, and now thist. Could we please make an effort.

Comment: ? converts the decimal portion of the number into an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to convert one number to the common precision level and then compare the numbers. If they are the same use `number with bigger precision' logic (in pseudo code):

```
return (number1 == number2) ? [number with bigger precision logic] : number1 - number2
```

In Java code

```
class Money {
   long units;
   int precision;

   public Money (long un, int prec)  {
     units =  un;
     precision = prec;
   }

   public int compareTo(Money other) {
      int preResult = this.precision - other.precision;
      long first =  (preResult > 0) ?  ((long)(this.units / Math.pow(10, preResult))) : this.units;
      long second = (preResult < 0) ?  ((long)(other.units * Math.pow(10, preResult))) : other.units;
      return (first == second) ? preResult : Long.compare(first, second);
   }

   public static void test() {
      Money first  = new Money(2345L, 4);
      Money second = new Money(234567L, 6);
      System.out.println(first.compareTo(second));
   }

}
```

EDIT: There was an error in the code. Changing the 1 in both tenary checks to 0 fixes this issue

Comment: On second thought, I don't think this would work. If I have `0.2345` and `0.234567` and i'm testing to see if the first is greater than the second, `0.234567` would be chopped to `0.2345`. If I use `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` it would work but if the test case is whether `0.2345` is greater than `0.23454` it would fail. Perhaps i'm missing something?

Comment: First you convert one number to the same precision level so `0.2345 == 0.2345`. The second number `0.234567` has bigger precision,  so it is bigger thus -1 needs to be return. if the first number has bigger precision 1 needs to be returned. Otherwise return `number1 - number2`

Comment: thanks for the help I really appreciate it. I understand your method a lot better and I think it might just work. I ran some tests on the code you provided and it fails on this line. `Assert.assertEquals(-1, new Money(152L, 2).compareTo(Money(22L, 1)));` It's giving me back 1. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: "4.33" and "5234" also errors but everything else seems fine. EDIT: Further testing shows that it's the second number that is causing the error. Here's a full pastebin of the tests run, the commented parts are the parts that failed. http://pastebin.com/QNFaKsj2

Comment: Sorry for triple posting but i've changed the code and so far the tests seem to be giving the right responses back. Would you mind double checking?

Comment: I run short test and it works. Thanks for catching `1 vs 0` bug.

Comment: There's actually another bug in the code. It has to do with comparing 0 to 0.123. I've fixed it as well with an if statement. However, I ran some performance tests and it would seem that this isn't that much faster than BigDecimal's compareTo method. It's only around x4 faster and only for precision that is at 2. Anything higher and it will be x5 slower than BigDecimal's compareTo method. Thank you for your help regardless!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just do it like this:

```
public int compareTo(Money other) {

    return Double.compare(units/Math.pow(10, precision), other.getUnits()/Math.pow(10,  other.getPrecision()));
}
```